# framework to generate XSD from java object instance

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I need some framework to create xsd from java object.
i know jaxb and xstream but those frameworks is not what i need, because those framework generate from java class XSD, but i need to generate from values of instance of java XSD.
for example:

My java class:

```
public class Example {

   public List<String> elements;

}
```

Insert value Yo the Object:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        Example e = new Example();

        e.elements,add("a"); 

        e.elements,add("b");

        e.elements,add("c");

        // Now i want to generate e.elements to xsd file like example below.


    }
}
```

This is my expected xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="something">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: If you found one of the answers helpful, please consider marking them accordingly. Or comment on why not.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not XJC, but a different JAXB tool namely schemagen.
It's usage is pretty straightforward and clearly explained [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/usage_schemagen.html).

And as an example, I tried the following:

**Example.java**

```java
@XmlType(namespace = Namespaces.SOME_NAMESPACE,
     propOrder = {"a", "b", "c"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Example {

    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "requiredElementValue")
    private String a;

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    private String b;

    @XmlAttribute(required = false)
    private String c;

}
```

**Relevant portion of pom.xml**

```xml
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemagen</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schemagen</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformSchemas>
                    <transformSchema>
                        <uri>http://some/namespace</uri>
                        <toPrefix>some</toPrefix>
                        <toFile>myschema.xsd</toFile>
                    </transformSchema>
                </transformSchemas>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
```

**And the output -> myschema.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://some/namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="example">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" default="requiredElementValue"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **Maven** tool using [**jaxb2:xjc plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html)

Simple example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schema1-xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaFiles>schema1.xsd</schemaFiles>
                <packageName>com.example.foo</packageName>
                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.schema1XjcStaleFlag</staleFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Plugin [**usage**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Downvoted because this answer deals with generating Java files for an existing XSD while the (admittedly confusing) question is on how to generate XSD for existing Java files. Schemagen turned out to be the solution.